# Troubleshooting (sometimes) long boot ups with ssd

Tags: windows-10, boot

I'm asking for help here because I don't know what to do now except, formatting the pc.

Let me explain what happens when I turn on the pc:

1. Everything turns on: MB, GC, fans, LEDs, all I/O devices
   Classic BIOS window (press F2 to access BIOS..) that expires in 3 seconds, as it is supposed to do;
2. The press F2 to.. is replaced by a loading wheel, all I/O devices are shut down (LEDs turn off) but not the MB, GC, fans and PC's LEDs;
3. This goes on for more than one minute, until all I/O devices turn back on and immediately after Windows 10 log in happens and everything works fine.

This started some months ago, it is not supposed to happen, I can't identify an event (such as a new device) that might have caused the issue.
It doesn't happen all the times (90%+ maybe?), I can't 100% force it to work correctly but, when it does, it only takes 5 seconds, or less, to boot up.

I tried a lot of scenarios by unplugging the different I/O devices but I can't find a pattern, I'm only sure that is always happens if I restart the PC.

I thought it could have been my USB ports not shutting down with my pc, but I changed it via BIOS and the problem is still present.

I tried some WPR analysis regarding the boot phase and everything seems ok, only the postboot lasts 50 seconds (the previous phases only a couple of seconds each) but this involves auto runs processes and I'm sure the 1+ minutes of loading (which is before the Windows log in) happens before. Basically this "black out" isn't recorded at all.

All my drivers are up to date and there isn't a single problem when the PC is turned on

My motherboard is an ASUS z170 and the graphics card is an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050Ti, only one hdd/ssd connected. Nothing out of the ordinary with my machine.

Is there something that I can try? Can you guess the source of the problem?